# Access properties inside html in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I work with laravel/livewire and I have a problem. I declare my property xml and import a xml file in the boot function. What I want is to show an element of my xml file inside my button. But when i go to my website, i have a problem who tell <<Undefined variable $xml>>
This is my class and the view I want to show in my page

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Pages;

use App\Services\ConfigXmlService;
use Livewire\Component;

class ModuleA extends Component
{
    private $xml;

    public function boot(ConfigXmlService $configXmlService)
    {
        $this->xml = $configXmlService->importXML('xml/module-a_SM.xml');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pages.module-a')
            ->layout('layouts.module', ['title' => 'Module A', 'module' => 'A']);
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <button> {{$xml->page[0]->mot1}} </button> 
    <button>choix 2</button>
    <p>description aleatoire</p>
</div>
```

a little extract of my xml file

```
<page>               
        <mot1>Effluence</mot1>
        <mot2>Affluence</mot2>
        <definition1>Émanation, vapeur.</definition1>
        <definition2>Rassemblement d’une foule de personnes dans un même lieu.</definition2>                
    </page>
```

Someone can help me? I can dump the xml data but I dont know what is wrong when i when to access it in my html

**and if i change private to public string xml it show me this \n \n ...etc and not the data

Comment: Did you try changing the scope of the `$xml` variable to `public`?

Comment: yeah but it didnt show the good thing, It show me the /n and some text but not the data

Comment: It show me all the \n in the file @EduardoGalván

Comment: private scoped variables are not passed to the views, which is why you get an undefined error.  They are also not persisted between requests either.  If the data is only being set once you would be better to use the mount method and not boot.  boot refreshes on each interaction.  Without more info its hard to help, what do you get if you dd($this->xml->page[0]) in the Component Class?

Comment: @ColinMD, If i put my $xml public and I dd($this->xml->page[0]) inside the mount function, I get a error for the page[0] (Attempt to read property "page" on string)

Comment: I found the right thing: I put my $xml property protected and it work! I can access to the page/mots into my html